# How to monitor server-side log when using Meteor and Meteor Up

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-up

I'm using Meteor and Meteor UP for deployment.
So far so good.
I can deploy my project to my test Ubuntu server.

My problem is I don't know how to debug on server.
If I use node.js and express, I can just write console.log("some error") to see logs.

The log file seems /var/log/upstart/.log
But I could only find

```
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
```

Is there any way to output "console.log(something)" ?

I use Ubuntu-14.04 and Meteor 1.1.0.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is. Do `console.log(something)` as you normally would in your server-side code. Then from the Ubuntu server in your meteor-up directory (same place where you do `mup deploy`), do `mup logs -f`

That will allow you to monitor the logs in real-time.

**UPDATE:** For those using the new `mupx`, you can check the logs with `mupx logs -f`

([ref](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#access-logs))

Comment: Thanks. I can monitor logs in if (Meteor.isServer) {}. Outside of the block seems to show up in browser.

Comment: The expected behavior is that anything on the server logs to the server, anything on the client logs to the client. It can also be on both client and server if your `console.log` is on both.

Comment: Thanks! If I only knew this for past 2 months.